# Website layout is different than it shows on the localhost

Tags: html, css

I have a website that shows differently on the web url than on the localhost, it shows perfectly on the localhost but when I run it on actual url it is shifted upwards, and the carousel goes through the navigation panel. I've tried almost everything that I could possibly think of.

The url is: http://www.cricketsaskatoon.com

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check your css for .navbar-wrapper or carousel.php line 17. There, just remove the following code:

```
position: absolute;
```

If you delete that, it shows perfectly fine for me on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Remove position from navbar-wrapper class

```
.navbar-wrapper {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

use above css in place of that. It might help you.

Also Remove `margin-top:-80px;` From carousal Div.

Comment: How does it work correctly on the localhost if that what is causing the problem?

Comment: I haven't check it on localhost so I can't explain it. Sorry For that. I just check website css and try to resolve issue to help you. :)

Comment: I haven't checked it on localhost, we can't even if we wanted to because it is on the OP computer, but the OP mentioned it worked well on localhost,  "*it shows perfectly on the localhost but when I run it on actual url it is shifted upwards*"

Comment: I can't explain this query.

Answer (score 0):

You really should place more code.

From your website's source code, it seems that your carousel is placed in a specific div class:

```
<div style="margin-top:-80px;">
  <!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```

Change the div style. Or rather, just make the margin 80 instead of -80. That should work.

`<div style="margin-top:80px;">`

[Image with the changed style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyKf1.jpg)`

Using a container tag instead should help too.